# What is the best way of going about making a windows desktop overlay app?

Tags: overlay, desktop

I want to make a Desktop overlay application that is always on top of the desktop for windows. Like Wallpaper engine or Rainmeter for example . I want to go for minimal resource use. I have tried using WPF .Net but i got the limitation of not being able to bypass the show desktop shortcut (WINDOWS+D). I need something that will not be minimized when this shortcut gets used.
I'm willing to look into any coding language or framework. I just need a little push down the right path!

Thank you in advance